# Android wrap group of buttons in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an empty "horizontal" LinearLayout that I programatically add multiple buttons to. Each button is a folder in the complete file path that the user is browsing.

This works just fine but the buttons squeeze in width with each folder name and increase in height as the LinearLayout tries to fit each button on the same line.

How can I make it so that once the list of buttons is too wide (with no word wrapping in the button text) that the next button will just go to the next line? Something similar to word wrapping in a TextView?

I would just like the user to be able to jump back in the folder tree quickly instead of having to press the back button a bunch of times.

The amount of buttons and the text in each button is totally variable.

Comment: have you looked at using [this android flow layout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout)?

Comment: the flow layout worked perfectly, thanks